# typing.Tuple from list of types

Tags: python, typing

I have a list of type objects and want to construct a typing.Tuple object. Is there a way to do this?

```py
tys = [int, str]    # This is known only at runtime
x = typing.Tuple(tys)   # TypeError: Type Tuple cannot be instantiated; use tuple() instead
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: For clarification about the question-

What I am trying to do - visit a Tuple in python AST and annotate its type. For this the list `tys` is made out of a loop (and so, I could not start with a tuple in the start). Now, I definitely have to annotate it with a `typing.Tuple` object and hence the question.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error was that `Type Tuple cannot be instantiated; use tuple() instead`. I didn't understand earlier, but it is clear now and I have written that as an answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that. Also it will help if you explain the desired goal here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sure. I will add it to the question and explain the goal. Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
x = typing.Tuple[tuple(tys)] # This works
```

Edit: This works for all typing constructs. For eg. while `typing.Union(tys)` and `typing.Union[tys]` will give an error, `typing.Union[tuple(tys)]` works. I am not sure if this is a general "python" thing, or it is special with the typing module. I will update this answer once I know that.

Comment: Since `tys` is a list, why aren't you using `typing.List`?

Comment: @Barmar I was visiting a tuple in python AST and so, I am sure I need `typing.Tuple`. The list is created by visiting individual items in the tuple and hence, it is a from a loop (that is why I had to start with a list and could not start with a tuple itself).

Comment: can you simplify this to `typing.Tuple[tys]`? I'm not familiar with the `typing` library, so I don't know if this works or not.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that gives the error - `Tuple[t0, t1, ...]: each t must be a type. Got [<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>].` So, I think in Python 3.8.0, it is not supported. I am not sure about the current development.

Comment: So the two syntaxes appear to mean different things. What is the type that you want here? From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple), your suggestion here that "works" appears to mean a tuple with one element whose type is itself a tuple. But I may be reading the docs incorrectly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I thought exactly the same thing and could not figure out what to do and hence the question. But turns out, this works - `Tuple[int, str] == Tuple[tuple(tys)]` gives `True`. Now, `Tuple[(int, str)]` is not an error, but `Tuple[(int, str), (int)]` is an error. So, it looks like, in the special case of single tuple entry, the tuple is opened, but more than one entries are not accepted - they should be appropriate type objects. Also, that if you want a tuple of tuple, then you should use `Tuple` inside `Tuple`.(I am not sure about this, but this is my understanding.)

Comment: Most likely `(int)` should be `(int,)` (trailing comma to create a tuple). And depending on what you mean, you probably need to use `Union` to provide a list of acceptable types (i.e. the type can be a tuple with two elements or a tuple with one element).

Comment: Yes @Code-Apprentice, you are right about the comma thing. But what I meant in the example was that - `[(int, str)]` is interpreted as `[int, str]`. So, naturally, I thought that maybe `[(int, str), (str,)]` will be interpreted as `[int, str, str]`. But that is not the case. I think this interpretation happens only when there is a single tuple inside square brackets. But, I am not an expert in this, and I did not refer to the language manual. Maybe it is a python thing, or perhaps it is a typing module thing.